# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog on Java Platform Enterprise Edition (JSP)

Tags: java, jsp

I just wanted to know can we use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` in Java Server Page(*.JSP) like `MsgBox("Message")` in ASP.NET?

I have tried this code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JOptionPane"%>

<%
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message");  
%>
```

and I got this :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Simple, you can't do that. Why don't you use Javascript's alert?

Comment: heyy, thanks for your responsive reply. I just wanted to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as calling JOptionPane.showMessageDialog requires the following params

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message)
                          throws HeadlessException

Brings up an information-message dialog titled "Message".

Parameters:
    parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used
    message - the Object to display
```

The parent component here should be valid subclass of Component class or in layman terms some kind of swing or awt frame.Which JSP won't be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing desktop technology with web. It is not possible

Comment: Haha, thanks. I just Wanted to know. Like .Net technology, we can still use MsgBox in their web Technology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with `jdk1.7`.
See this jsp file:

```
<% 
    String msg = request.getParameter("msg");
    if (msg == "") 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"name cannot be blank "+msg);
    if (msg != null) 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome   "+msg);
 %>
<form name='form'>
    Enter name <input name='msg'> <br>
    <input type="button" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, 
instead use `javascript alert`.